# Persist background color of selected day in angular-bootstrap-calendar

Tags: angularjs

In https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar, how can I keep the background color of the selected day from while in the month view?

I am trying to persist the background color of the day that I click on a different color than the other days on the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you can set the background color of the selected cell using the `cal-day-open` css class, which is dynamically added by the calendar directive.

So adding something like this in your stylesheet should give you the desired behavior:

```
.cal-day-open{
    background: #ffcccc; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  Thank you!  One issue though, is that it doesn't work when the slidebox is diabled (cell-auto-open-disabled="true").  Do you know any way around that?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do this, but looking at the docs and with a little experimenting, I think you need a combination of the `on-date-range-select` and `cell-modifier` functions to do this. You should be able to set a `vm.selectedDate` variable within `on-date-range-select` and then check that value against the date value for each cell in `cell-modifier` function and if it's the same then set the cell's css class to highlight it. Since `cell-modifier` runs on first load, you would have to invoke it each time the date cell is clicked, so from within the `on-date-range-select` function.

Comment: Thanks, i'll research that.  For now, as a band aid fix, I set the slidebox to display: none in css.  Cheers for your help!